# Unity netcode: ClientRpc inconsistent behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We are working on a multiplayer game for several months, today we are encountering a very weird bug related to ClientRpc calls and Scriptable Objects.
The server runs all instructions but the clients doesn't receive ClientRpc Call at a specific point.
here is a snippet of the NetworkBehaviour

```cs
public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
 
        if (!IsServer) return;
        var reqObjects = new int[3];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TestClientRpc(); // This one is received by the clients with no issues
            Debug.Log($"Before Get Random {i}");
            var collectable = CollectableObject.GetRandom();
            TestClientRpc(); // This one is not received by the clients
            Debug.Log($"After Get Random {i}"); // even though this log is printed by the server
            reqObjects[i] = (int) collectable.type;
        }
 
        requiredObjects.Value = new Vector3Int(reqObjects[0], reqObjects[1], reqObjects[2]); //At this point the server receive the OnValueChanged notification but not the client
 
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void TestClientRpc()
    {
        Debug.Log("Client received call from server");

    }
```

Here is a snippet of the Scriptable Object code:

```cs
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Quests/Collectable Object")]
    public class CollectableObject : ScriptableObject
    {
        private static readonly List<CollectableObject> ListOfCollectables = new ();
 
        public void OnEnable()
        {
            Debug.Log("Adding new entry to list of collectables");
            ListOfCollectables.Add(this);
        }
 
        public static CollectableObject GetRandom()
        {
            var randomCollectableIdx = Random.Range(0, ListOfCollectables.Count);
            return ListOfCollectables[randomCollectableIdx];
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help debugging this code..
Thanks

Expected result :
"Client received call from server" shown 6 times
and requiredObjects value get updated in server and clients
Got Result:
"Client received call from server" shown 1 time
and requiredObjects value doesn't update in client only

Comment: `requiredObjects value doesn't update in client` makes totally sense since that is only assigned at the server side ... At the client side in the console is there maybe `Collapse` enabled? In that case the message will only appear once but with a counter right to it ...